# UploadedFileCleanerListener must implement at least one listener interface Primefaces

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I have this problem when I try to deploy my project in Jboss EAP 7.4.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT010012: Listener class class  org.primefaces.webapp.UploadedFileCleanerListener must implement at least one listener interface                                                              
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.api.ListenerInfo.<init>(ListenerInfo.java:47)                                                                                                                  
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.4.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.addListener(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1191)                                               
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.4.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.createServletConfig(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:859)                                        
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.4.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.start(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:276)                                                      
        at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)                                                                                     
        at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)                                                                                          
        ... 6 more
```

This after to update versions to Spring boot 3.1.4, JakartaEE 9.1.0 and Primefaces 13.0.2

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>13.0.2</version>
            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
        </dependency>
```

Thanks!

Comment: WildFly/EAP already provides Jakarta EE out the box. Your pom.xml **must** have `<scope>provided</scope>` for it. Do it and retry. Otherwise your runtime classpath ends up in a big mess caused by duplicate JEE API classes conflicting each other. Do not try to treat WildFly/EAP as if it were a barebones servletcontainer such as Tomcat. By the way, mixing Spring Boot and Jakarta EE is surely weird. It looks like you aren't really using Spring Boot. Normally you'd deploy it as a JAR with an embedded servletcontainer such as Tomcat instead of deploying a WAR to a normal Jakarta EE server.

Comment: OKay thank you! I'll try it